# Issues after installing Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I got a new laptop this week (Win10), installed Visual Studio 2015 community, followed by Xamarin. I've created a blank Android project, uncommented the `SetContentView(...)` line in MainActivity.cs, then build the solution. However I'm running into various problems when I try to run it:

The list of emulators (next to the green "run" button) only contains two entries: "*Android_accelarated_x86 (Android 6.0 - API 23)*" and "*Android_ARMv7a (Android 6.0 - API 23)*". Is this normal? The Xamarin doc'n seems to suggest that a number of "Xamarin xxx" emulators would be installed.

When I run the project against "Android_accelarated_x86", the emulator starts up, Visual Studio reports the deployment is successful, but Visual Studio stops debugging. In the output window I see this:

> InspectorDebugSession(0): StateChange: Start -> EntryPointBreakpointRegistered
>   InspectorDebugSession(0): Constructed
>   Android application is debugging.
>   Couldn't connect to logcat, GetProcessId returned: 0
>   InspectorDebugSession(0): HandleTargetEvent: TargetExited
>   InspectorDebugSession(0): Disposed

If I hit run again, the app `seems` to start on the emulator, but then a message appears saying "Unfortunately xxx has stopped" (where xxx is my project name). The above messages appear in the VS windows again (apart from the one about 'Couldn't connect to logcat...').

I've also noticed that the "Manage Virtual Devices" item in the dropdown is greyed out, so I presumably can't try creating a different emulator?

Answer (score 0):

Shooting from the hip on this one but do you have the Android SDK installed? It should install a number of other emulators and give you access to the device manager.

There are emulators you can INstal with Visual Studio. Emulators that come with the Android SDK and emulators that install with Xamarin Studio.

One additional thing to try would be to install Xamarin Studios. It does a slightly better job in my experience of setting up your environment then VS Does.

Comment: It seems I have two versions of the SDK - one under C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Android\ and one under C:\Program Files (x86)\Android. Visual Studio Xamarin settings are all pointing to the latter, and launching the avd and sdk managers from VS seems okay. If I launch the sdk manager from the Win start menu then most items are not installed. And if I launch the avd manager from the start menu then the above emulators are listed, but with question marks in the columns alongside the names.

Comment: I actually had the same thing today and spent most of the day blowing it all away and reseting it up. It was causing a different error for me though. Can you lauch the emulator with your solution in Xamarin Studio?

Comment: I'm just downloading Xamarin Studio now, to see if that's any better. Just curious, during the Xamarin install it asks where to install the SDK to - it listed two existing locations (C:\users\xxx\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Universal, and \Mono for Android, I seem to remember), with a button to add another location. I clicked this, and specified C:\Program Files (x86)\Android. What should I have done here? I've also heard of issues with spaces in the Android folder path?

Comment: Re Xamarin Studio, it seems they've scrapped it for Windows, now that there is VS integration!

Comment: C:\users\xxx\AppData\Local\ is the "norm" or default

Comment: Just to chip in here, you can find the location Xamarin is looking at under Visual Studio > Tools > Options > Xamarin > Android

Comment: @AlanClark it was all pointing to C:\Program Files..., but odd that there was  another under C:\Users\.... Now wiping and reinstalling yet again. Will be getting divorced at this rate - have been trying to get this to work for the last 4 days over the xmas break... Very frustrating - I've never got Xamarin to work on my desktop at home or at work, and colleagues have had similar issues which were never solved.

Comment: @AndrewStephens Could you drop an email to contact (at) xamarin dot com for my attention?  I think it might be easier to work through these issues by email and then follow up here once we've had the opportunity to properly work through them.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the `Manage Virtual Devices` is referring to Xamarin Android Player VMs (which is now deprecated).  We're working on getting this removed if Xamarin Android Player isn't present.

To create / edit / fix your Google AVD VMs you should select `Android Emulator Manager`.  Regarding the number of devices listed, I'd probably ensure everything Xamarin is updated..

`Visual Studio > Tools > Options > Xamarin > Other > Check for Updates`

..and also update all your SDK components.  If you have an Intel CPU you should use the x86 images for best performance.  If you haven't already installed this you can get it here:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager

If you update any images it could be that your AVD needs repairing, which you can do in the Android Emulator Manager by selecting the relevant image and clicking `Repair`.

Also, you will only be able to deploy to devices that your project is targeting, so it's worthwhile checking the AndroidManifest.xml or by right-clicking your project and checking the 'minimum' and 'target' Android API levels to ensure you're encompassing the AVDs you have created.

Comment: All the points you mentioned seem to be fine. Re the x86 images, do I use the "Intel Atom x86 system image" or the "Google APIs Intel Atom x86 system image"? (I also have "Atom_64" versions too).

Comment: The Google APIs version has the apps and APIs that ship on Google and most other commercially available devices.  The other is plain Android without Google Maps or other Google frameworks included.